# Select all rows related by a column

Tags: sql-server

i have a Url table

```
UrlId   Followedby
1            NULL
2            1
3            2
```

i want to write a sp which take urlid as parameter and return all rows.
GetAllUrls 3
and it will return above rows.

Can above doable without cursor ?

Comment: right now i have a object in my DbAccess layer which is a linked list and load all followed by url one by one .i want to retain the linked list but like to load all urls in single DB hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) it would look like this

```
declare @UrlId int = 3

;with C as 
(
  select U.UrlId,
         U.Followedby
  from Url as U
  where U.UrlId = @UrlId
  union all
  select U.UrlId,
         U.Followedby
  from Url as U
    inner join C
      on U.UrlId = C.Followedby
)
select UrlId,
       Followedby 
from C
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119027/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).

Comment: How can i use The CTE in my case .my SP is suposed to work for an urlid.